# How to merge two dictionaries in javascript

Tags: javascript, dictionary, lodash

I have two arrays of objects:

Array1:

```
var myArr1 = [];
myArr1["1"]={any:1,some:1};
myArr1["2"]={any:2,some:2};
myArr1["3"]={any:3,some:3};
```

Array2:

```
var myArr2 = [];
myArr2["1"]={other:1};    
myArr2["2"]={other:2};
```

And I want them to be merged by their keys into a new Attribute, so the result will be:

```
[
  {any:1,some:1,myNewAttribute:{other:1}},
  {any:2,some:2,myNewAttribute:{other:2}},
  {any:3,some:3,myNewAttribute:{other:3}}
]
```

I tried to achieve it with lodash's `_.merge()` but I failed miserably. `_.merge` only adds the second array after the first, but does not match their keys / ids.

Comment: Is this pseudo code? Javascript has objects, not dicts. What exactly didn’t work for you with `_.merge`?

Comment: Looking at your desired result, the first element has a `some` property, but not the second or third? Is that really what you want, or do you want the `some` property on all elements in the result?

Comment: i edited the question. I know how to manually combine them with a `for`-loop, but I wanted to keep it elegant with lodash..

Comment: Do you really want to use lodash, or is that just what you thought might be a good approach?

Comment: @torazaburo thanks, i edited the question

Comment: You know that `array["1"]` is equivalent to `array[1]`, right? Are you intending to skip over the 0 index, by the way?

Comment: Now your desired result has an `other` property on the third element, but that comes from where? It is not on `myArr2`.

Comment: @torazaburo the "index" comes from a database and does not have to start with 0. it could be 122, 145, 1001,10002 ..

Comment: @ManuelSchiller ... regarding yours "... but I wanted to keep it elegant with lodash ..." - if it is about elegance, just pick the right tool. In your case it should be an arrays native `reduce` method. (And in case of having to use *lodash* mandatory, choose its `reduce` instead of its `merge` method.)

Comment: Do `myArr1` and `myArr2` have the same indices defined? What if they don't?

Comment: You should probably use an object instead of an array if the indices aren't sequential starting from zero. If you have one element with the index of 10002, you're creating a (sparse) array with 10003 elements.

Comment: @torazaburo yes they are always the same length and always have the same indices

Comment: @Juhana What's wrong with a sparse array?

Comment: @torazaburo Nothing (apart from non-obvious pitfalls), but if it's used like an object and not as an array, it's better to use an object rather than an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could map the second array to a new property and merge later.

With lodash

```js
var data1 = [{ any: 1, some: 1 }, { any: 2, some: 2 }, { any: 3, some: 3 }],
    data2 = [{ other: 1 }, { other: 2 }, { other: 3 }];

console.log(_.merge(data1, _.map(data2, x => ({ myNewAttribute: x }))));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

With ES6, without lodash

```js
var data1 = [{ any: 1, some: 1 }, { any: 2, some: 2 }, { any: 3, some: 3 }],
    data2 = [{ other: 1 }, { other: 2 }, { other: 3 }];

console.log(data1.map((a, i) => Object.assign({}, a, { myNewAttribute: data2[i] })));
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need lodash:

```
myArr1.map((e1, idx) => Object.assign({}, e1, {myNewAttribute: myArr2[idx]}))
```

You could get fancy and write a little function called `map2`, which takes two arrays, and invokes a callback with the two elements:

```
function map2(a1, a2, fn) {
  return a1.map((elt, idx) => fn(elt, a2[idx]);
}
```

Now you can write the solution as

```
map2(myArr1, myArr2, (e1, e2) => Object.assign({}, e1, {myNewAttribute: e2}))
```

From the perspective of program design, what we are doing here is "separating concerns". The first concern is the abstract operation of looping over two arrays in parallel and doing *something* with each pair of elements. That is what is represented by `map2`. The second concern is the specific way you want to combine the elements. That is what is represented by the function we are passing to `map2`. This could be made clearer and somewhat self-documenting by writing it separately:

```
function combineObjects(e1, e2) { 
  return Object.assign({}, e1, {myNewAttribute: e2}); 
}

map2(myArr1, myArr2, combineObjects);
```

Of course, in the real world, you'd want to handle the case where the two arrays were of different length, pass an index to the callback as a third parameter for use if necessary, support a third `thisArg`-type parameter analogous to `map`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
var first = [{any:1,some:1},{any:2,some:2},{any:3,some:3}];
var second = [{other:1},{other:2},{other:3}];

for(var i = 0; i < first.length; i++){
    if(first[i] && second[i]){
         first[i]['mycustomitem'] = second[i];
    }
}

console.log(first);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to prove, what I did comment 30 minutes ago -
[How to merge two dictionaries in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39271799/how-to-merge-two-dictionaries-in-javascript#comment65880017_39271799) -
there is a possible `reduce` approach ...

... firstly provided as *lodash* based example ...

```js
var
    myArr1 = [
        {any: 1, some: 1},
        {any: 2, some: 2},
        {any: 3, some: 3}
    ],
    myArr2 = [
        {other: 1},
        {other: 2}
    ],

    mergedObjectList = _.reduce(myArr1, function (collector, item_1, idx) {
        var
            item_2 = collector[idx],
            merger = _.assign({}, item_1, item_2);

        // or whatever one wants to do to `merger` with `myNewAttribute`

        collector[idx] = merger;

        return collector;

    }, _.clone(myArr2));


console.log("myArr1 : ", myArr1);
console.log("myArr2 : ", myArr2);
console.log("mergedObjectList : ", mergedObjectList);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

... and secondly as *language core only* based example ...

```js
var
    myArr1 = [
        {any: 1, some: 1},
        {any: 2, some: 2},
        {any: 3, some: 3}
    ],
    myArr2 = [
        {other: 1},
        {other: 2}
    ],

    mergedObjectList = myArr1.reduce(function (collector, item_1, idx) {
        var
            item_2 = collector[idx],
            merger = Object.assign({}, item_1, item_2);

        // or whatever one wants to do to `merger` with `myNewAttribute`

        collector[idx] = merger;

        return collector;

    }, Array.from(myArr2));


console.log("myArr1 : ", myArr1);
console.log("myArr2 : ", myArr2);
console.log("mergedObjectList : ", mergedObjectList);
```

Comment: @NinaScholz - thanks for the hint, it happened accidentally and has been fixed by now.

Answer (score -1):

Try this function:

```js
function mergeDictionary(_dctn1,_dctn2)
{
   var newDict = [];
   for(var i in _dctn1)
   {
       newDict[i] = _dctn1[i];
   }
   for(var j in _dctn2)
   {
       if(newDict[j] == undefined)
       {
            newDict[j] = _dctn2[j];
       }
       else
       {
            for(var k in _dctn2[j])
            {
                newDict[j][k] = _dctn2[j][k]; 
            }
       }
   
   }
   
   return newDict;
}


var myArr1 = [];
myArr1["1"]={any:1,some:1};
myArr1["2"]={any:2,some:2};
myArr1["3"]={any:3,some:3};

var myArr2 = [];
myArr2["1"]={other:1};    
myArr2["2"]={other:2};

console.log(mergeDictionary(myArr1, myArr2));
```

Comment: Why are you using the term "dictionary" when JS does not even have dictionaries? The objects in question here are arrays. Why would you write a loop to copy an array when you could write `newDict = _dctn1.slice();`?

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I made your code an executable snippet. If you run it you'll notice that it doesn't look anything like what the question asks for.

Comment: Actually it should be object instead of array